# How to set annotations to treat labels as nouns in spaCy library, Python

Tags: nlp, tokenize, spacy

I have this labelled sentence:

```
[x] moved to [y] in [z].
```

How can I set annotations for [x], [y] as a noun, [z] as a datetime? I referred to https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions but did not find the thing I wanted or I missed it.

Comment: What types of annotation are you trying to set? You want to set POS tags for `[x]` and `[y]` and an entity span for `[z]`?

Comment: I try to set POS tags for all. I can treat [z] as a NUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the POS with tokenizer special cases (https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases):

```
orth = "[z]"
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(orth, [{"ORTH": orth, "TAG": "NUM"}])
```

(It's honestly kind of weird to have the tokenizer setting tags, but this functionality is there for now.)

Comment: Thank for your answer! I set labels to all subjects (Subject Group) and try to get the related words with this group.